# How to plot a histogram of a pandas series of lists

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram that shows the frequency of genre_ids across movie data. The data is currently stored as a list of ids in a pandas dataframe column, since some movies are several genres and looks like this:

```
genre_ids
[35]                         
[18]                          
[35, 10749]                   
[18, 10749]                   
[35, 18, 10749]
```

How do I plot a histogram such that the values on the axis are just the genre ids individually and not the lists themselves? I searched everywhere for this question and couldn't figure it out. So far I'm just using:

```
movie_data['genre_ids'].hist()
```

Where movie_data is the data frame. And I want the histogram to look like:

```
x
x   x  
x   x  x
35 18 10749
```

Instead of:

```
x
x              x
x      x       x      x
[35] [18,35] [18] [18,10749]
```

for example

Comment: I'm guessing the genre IDs are strings?

Comment: And we'll need more info on how to differentiate a genre ID from a movie ID.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing the histogram, you need to bring out the elements from the lists.

This should do the job:

```
form Pandas import Series
movie_data['genre_ids'].apply(Series).stack().hist()
```